# Debounce similar requests with reactor-grpc

Tags: java, grpc, project-reactor

In order to offload my database, I would like to debounce similar requests in a gRPC service (say for instance that they share the same id part of the request) that serves an API which does not have strong requirements in terms of latency. I know how to do that with vanilla gRPC but I am sure what kind of API of Mono I can use.

The API calling directly the db looks like this:

```
public Mono<Blob> getBlob(
      Mono<MyRequest> request) {
    return request.
       map(reader.getBlob(request.getId()));
```

I have a feeling I should use `delaySubscription` but then it does not seem that `groupBy` is part of the `Mono` API that gRPC services handle.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfeclty ok to detect duplicates not using reactive operators:

```java
// Guava cache as example.
private final Cache<String, Boolean> duplicatesCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterWrite(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
    .build();

public Mono<Blob> getBlob(Mono<MyRequest> request) {
    return request.map(req -> {
        var id = req.getId();
        var cacheKey = extractSharedIdPart(id);
        if (duplicatesCache.getIfPresent(cacheKey) == null) {
            duplicatesCache.put(cacheKey, true);
            return reader.getBlob(id);
        } else {
            return POISON_PILL; // Any object that represents debounce hit.
                                // Or use flatMap() + Mono.error() instead.
        }
    });
}
```

If for some reason you absolutely want to use reactive operators, then first you need to convert incoming grpc requests into `Flux`. This can be achieved using thirdparty libs like [salesforce/reactive-grpc](https://github.com/salesforce/reactive-grpc) or directly:

```java
class MyService extends MyServiceGrpc.MyServiceImplBase {

    private FluxSink<Tuple2<MyRequest, StreamObserver<MyResponse>>> sink;

    private Flux<Tuple2<MyRequest, StreamObserver<MyResponse>>> flux;

    MyService() {
        flux = Flux.create(sink -> this.sink = sink);
    }


    @Override
    public void handleRequest(MyRequest request, StreamObserver<MyResponse> responseObserver) {
        sink.next(Tuples.of(request, responseObserver));
    }

    Flux<Tuple2<MyRequest, StreamObserver<MyResponse>>> getFlux() {
        return flux;
    }
}
```

Next you subscribe to this flux and use operators you like:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var mySvc = new MyService();
    var server = ServerBuilder.forPort(DEFAULT_PORT)
        .addService(mySvc)
        .build();
    server.start();
    mySvc.getFlux()
        .groupBy(...your grouping logic...)
        .flatMap(group -> {
            return group.sampleTimeout(...your debounce logic...);
        })
        .flatMap(...your handling logic...)
        .subscribe();
}
```

But beware of using [groupBy](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#groupBy-java.util.function.Function-) with lots of distinct shared id parts:

> The groups need to be drained and consumed downstream for groupBy to work correctly. Notably when the criteria produces a large amount of groups, it can lead to hanging if the groups are not suitably consumed downstream (eg. due to a flatMap with a maxConcurrency parameter that is set too low).

Comment: The cache you propose does not have the behavior I want unfortunately: I really need to serve requests from a database read done _after_ the first request. I will try out the flux idea thanks. I am not sure why you are not using the same generated code in your example using flux (the parameter of the grpc handler is "MyRequest request, StreamObserver<MyResponse> responseObserver" instead of "Mono<something>".